# How to safely stop a IOCP WSARecv() task, and free the WSAOVERLAPPED structure?

Tags: c++, c, iocp

My IOCP server program will cost more and more memory while running. After tracking memory leak ,I found that some WSAOVERLAPPED structue feed to WSARecv() is never recycled. I think this is because some malignant client socket only establish connection but never send data or close. So i set a TimerQueueTimer() on every client socket to identify the timeout socket and delete them. But if I free the WSAOVERLAPPED structure when deleting the malignant socket, after a little while ,I got "Free Heap block 014C7D80 modified at 014C7DA8 after it was freed".

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
typedef struct _SocketState
{
   char operation; 
   SOCKET socket;   
   DWORD length;
   HANDLE hTimer;
   HANDLE hCompletion;
   WSAOVERLAPPED* thisOvl;
   char buf[MAX_BUF];
} SocketState;

static WSAOVERLAPPED* new_overlapped(void)
{
   return (WSAOVERLAPPED*)calloc(1, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
}

static void create_io_completion_port(void)
{
   cpl_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
   if (!cpl_port)
   {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        exit(1);
   }
}

static void post_reading(SocketState* socketState, WSAOVERLAPPED* ovl)
{
   DWORD flags = 0;
   WSABUF wsabuf = { MAX_BUF, socketState->buf };
   int err=0;
   memset(ovl, 0, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
   socketState->operation = OP_READ;
   socketState->thisOvl=ovl;
   if (WSARecv(socketState->socket, &wsabuf, 1, NULL, &flags, ovl, NULL)== SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
      err = WSAGetLastError();
      if (err != WSA_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("[%s:%d]WSARecv error\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        destroy_connection(socketState, ovl);
        return ;
      }
   }
   c_WSARecv++;
}

static void destroy_connection(SocketState* socketState, WSAOVERLAPPED* ovl)
{
    int err=0;
    if(socketState->hTimer != NULL)
    {
        DeleteTimerQueueTimer(hTimerQueue,socketState->hTimer,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
        socketState->hTimer = NULL; 
    }
    socketState->hCompletion=NULL; //newSocketState->hCompletion = cpl_port
    closesocket(socketState->socket);
    free(socketState);
    if(ovl!=0)
    {
       free(ovl);
    }
}
VOID CALLBACK TimerRoutine(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    SocketState* clientSocketState=(SocketState*)lpParam;
    if (lpParam != NULL)
    {
        if(clientSocketState->hCompletion != NULL)
        {
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(clientSocketState->hCompletion,-2,(ULONG_PTR)clientSocketState,clientSocketState->thisOvl);
            //should last parameter be NULL?
            //the "-2" is for identify this timeout io after GetQueuedCompletionStatus()
        }
    }
}
```

As I am using C rather then C++ for my server program, I am putting my self in very awkward situation. Basically I can't find a very good IOCP example in C :(.

Comment: So use whatever the async version of a read timeout is to detect the rogue client.

Comment: solution - is use reference counting. you pass pointer to `WSAOVERLAPPED` - add reference to it. I/O finished - call release.

Comment: @user207421 Can you be more specific, I am not very familiar with windows APIs. If my way of timing the client is just the wrong way?

Comment: then `socketState->operation = OP_READ;
   socketState->thisOvl=ovl;` of course design error. `socketState` must not hold pointer to overlapped. and state read - is invalid (by design) socket can at once do read and write. so several I/O requests. need visa vesra - overlapped must have pointer to `socketState`. and reference must be on it

Comment: @RbMm I am only using _thisOvl_ so I cat print out the number like  `printf("this ovl=%d\n",socketState->thisOvl)` to debug. I can delete it. Which part of overlapped structure should I pointer to socketState?

Comment: you need create self class inherited from `OVERLAPPED` and hold here pointer to `SocketState` and `operation`

Comment: @RbMm I have add more code above about my timer CALLBACK and socketState. How should I set a rouge io to be finished,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215162/discussion-between-dery-and-rbmm).

Comment: Traditionally, the one-off socket object and the many-off buffer+ovl are different structs.  Each buffer object then has its own overlapped block, hEvent pointing to its own buffer object, buffer object with pointer to socket object.  Your data is umm... non-optimal:(

Comment: @MartinJames Very inspiring for me! So the way I play with IOCP is not correct? And I should free the Ovl when I free the buffer object, right?

Comment: @Dery yes, (or repool it, if you are pooling buffers).  The overlapped block is tiny compared with typical data buffers, and has nearly the same lifetime, so it may as well be part of the buffer structure:)

Answer (score 2):

`OVERLAPPED` we can free only after I/O completed. so really all what need cancel I/O operation. this can be done by call [`CancelIoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func) or better by call [`closesocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-closesocket) (*The `closesocket` function will initiate cancellation on the outstanding I/O operations*). when I/O completed - you got pointer to `OVERLAPPED` passed to this I/O and after handle I/O result - you can free or reuse `OVERLAPPED`

---

you have structure associated with every socket - `SocketState` this is correct.
but what must and must not have this structure ?

it mandatory must implement reference counting (because it accessing from multiple threads in complex and unpredictable order). and hold handle to the socket. mandatory have some kind of rundown protection for socket handle for not use it after `closesocket/CancelIoEx` calls (it implementation already separate question). this is need because *A Winsock client must never issue `closesocket` on socket concurrently with another Winsock function call* but we need at any time be able call `closesocket` for cancel I/O on lost remote side.

from another side it must not have pointer to `OVERLAPPED` (or it shell class) because multiple I/O can be at once on socket. we can in parallel read and write. it must not have `operation` member too by same reason - read and write operations for example can be active in parallel. so code like

```
socketState->operation = OP_READ;
socketState->thisOvl=ovl;
```

is wrong by design. also no sense have `hCompletion` inside `SocketState` because `hCompletion` is not per socket. here is wrong place for store it.

also we need mandatory use not naked `OVERLAPPED` structure for pass it to I/O but self class inherited from `OVERLAPPED`. you need have additional members here - referenced pointer to your `SocketState` - because when I/O completed - you got back pointer to `OVERLAPPED` and need from it got pointer to your `socketState`. the `operation` also mandatory must be here (instead `SocketState`) because operation is per I/O but not per socket. so in very general can be next:

```
struct SocketState
{
    SOCKET socket;   
    HANDLE hTimer;
    ULONG dwRefCount;

    void AddRef();
    void Release();

    _NODISCARD SOCKET LockHandle();
    void Rundown();
    void UnlockHandle();// call closesocket on last unlock

    void OnIoComplete(ULONG operation, ULONG dwErrorCode, ULONG dwBytesTransfered, PVOID buf);

    void StartSomeIo(ULONG operation, PVOID buf, ULONG cb);

    void Close()
    {
        if (LockHandle())
        {
            Rundown();
            UnlockHandle();
        }
    }
};

struct UIrp : OVERLAPPED
{
    SocketState* socketState;
    ULONG operation;
    PVOID buf;

    UIrp(SocketState* socketState, ULONG operation, PVOID buf) 
        : socketState(socketState), operation(operation), buf(buf)
    {
        RtlZeroMemory(static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(this), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
        socketState->AddRef();
    }

    ~UIrp()
    {
        socketState->Release();
    }

    void OnIoComplete(ULONG dwErrorCode, ULONG dwBytesTransfered)
    {
        socketState->OnIoComplete(operation, dwErrorCode, dwBytesTransfered, buf);
        delete this;
    }
};

void SocketState::StartSomeIo(ULONG operation, PVOID buf, ULONG cb)
{
    if (UIrp* irp = new UIrp(this, operation, buf))
    {
        ULONG dwError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;

        if (SOCKET s = LockHandle())
        {
            dwError = WSA*(s,... irp, 0) == 0 ? NOERROR : WSAGetLastError();
            UnlockHandle();
        }

        switch (dwError)
        {
        case NOERROR:
        case WSA_IO_PENDING:
            break;
        default:
            irp->OnIoComplete(dwError, 0);
        }
    }
}

void PortLoop(HANDLE hCompletionPort)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        OVERLAPPED* lpOverlapped;
        ULONG dwBytesTransfered;
        ULONG_PTR CompletionKey;

        ULONG dwError = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &dwBytesTransfered, 
            &CompletionKey, &lpOverlapped, INFINITE) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

        // probably somehow use CompletionKey

        if (!lpOverlapped)
        {
            break;
        }

        static_cast<UIrp*>(lpOverlapped)->OnIoComplete(dwBytesTransfered, dwError);
    }
}
```

about

> set set a `TimerQueueTimer()` on every client socket

this is possible and correct by design but think not the best in case you have many sockets. i be inherit `SocketState` from `LIST_ENTRY` and insert all active sockets to the some list. and by timer periodically check timeout and close sockets

Comment: Thank you for answering my question with so much patience. I will take some time to rewrite my code and check if things works.

Comment: Sorry☹, I am not good at C++, any chance you can put your code into a C form?

Comment: @Dery - really my code is faster "c with classes" style.  you of couse can write this and in pure *c* if explicit use *this* pointer, not use inheritance but include `OVERLAPPED` as first member in `UIrp` etc.. but think no sense do this, if you can use *c++* compiler. here main not in language (*c or c++* ) but in understanding what and why i do. if you have more concrete question - ask, try give more concrete answer